# Sync up server side control from JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have the following scenario:

I have two panels, with links to switch between the two, these links DON'T post back the page, they call some JavaScript code that fades in and out the panels, changing their visibility.

In either panel I have a button that posts back the page, what happens is, after I fade in the second panel, my viewstate is invalid and my postback fails.

Is there a way to make my viewstate valid from JavaScript synching the visibility of these two panels? Or do I have to postback for this to work? If so, can I postback without the page blinking in my face and nicely fade the panels?

EDIT: This is somewhat the code that I have, obviously I have a bunch of controls inside the divs

```
<div id="step_one" class="lt-step-1">
    <asp:Button Text="Entrar" ID="btnPost1" OnClick="btnPost1_Click" ValidationGroup="Step1Val" CssClass="btn btn-primary lt-width-5" runat="server" />
    <a href="#" id="link_Step_Two"><span class="icon-repeat"></span>Step Two</a>
</div>
<div id="step_two" class="lt-step-2 hide">
    <asp:Button Text="Confirmar" ID="btnPost2" OnClick="btnPost2_Click" ValidationGroup="Step2Val" CssClass="btn btn-primary lt-width-5" runat="server" />
    <button type="button" id="btn_cancel_step_two" class="btn">Cancelar</button>
</div>

<script>
    require(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function ($) {

        'use strict';

        var $stepOne = $('#step_one'),
            $stepTwo = $('#step_two'),
            $allSteps = $('[id^="step_"]'),
            $link_Step_Two = $('#link_Step_Two'),
            $btnCancelStepTwo = $('#btn_cancel_step_two'),


        $link_Step_Two.on('click', function () {
            $allSteps.hide();
            $stepTwo.fadeIn();
        });

        $btnCancelStepTwo.on('click', function () {
            $allSteps.hide();
            $stepOne.fadeIn();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the exception that you are getting? Can we see some code?

Comment: Invalid ViewState yadayada, i'll try to edit some code here

Comment: change your server controls to html controls or use update panel

Comment: try putting runat=server on the step divs

Comment: Ok, it worked partialy, putting in an UpdatePanel solved the exception issue, but when I click btnPost2, i have to show Step1 again, and i shows correctly, but my link_Step_Two stops working

Comment: $("#<idOfParentContainerOutSideUpdatePanel>").on('click', '#link_Step_Two', function () {
            $allSteps.hide();
            $stepTwo.fadeIn();
        });

Try this. It should resolve "link_Step_Two stops working" issue

Comment: @Gnani nope :( didn't work

Comment: @Tejo I can't help much without seeing the code. I believe the problem is the click-event bound to the control is lost as update panels re-renders it. Look into jquery functions live()[outdated], on() to bind the function not to the control but to the page [preferably to a parent-container].

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I don't have enough points to just add a comment yet after Gnani above.  If it is just losing the jquery events, use the jquery [delegate function](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) against the form element.  Delegate will automatically hook up your events against your selector, even for elements that come into existence in the future, like when MS Ajax recreates your links.  I use this trick all the time.  Something like:

```
$("form").delegate('#link_Step_Two', 'click', function() {
  // Your code.
});

$("form").delegate('#btn_cancel_step_two', 'click', function() {
  // Your code.
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael, i've given up for now, but as soon as possible, i'll try your solution :)